# Connected to WiFi but unable to reach internet

Tags: wireless, internet

I am able to ping Google servers 8.8.8.8 and google.com but sudo apt-get update and internet through any browsers is not connecting.my machine is Dell Inspiron 3567 running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. how to resolve this issue.

Comment: maybe you have a firewall / iptables rule running that allows ICMP (Ping) but not http(s) requests?

Comment: How to remove those if any

Comment: To see if any iptables rules are set type: `sudo iptables -L`. Also check if your firewall is active `sudo ufw status`. If active you could deactivate the firewall rules that you do not want with the `ufw` command. Of if you prefer the gui, run and install `gufw`. If firewall is not active, we need to remove the iptables rules via command line. Therefor please post the output of `sudo iptables -L -n --line-numbers`